# Rails 3 "rake test" command output

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, shoulda, ruby-on-rails-3, testunit

running "rake test" with a simple Rails 3 project gives me the following output.

Why are two suites listed? I have one default test with "assert true" which is counted in the first suite but not the second.

Any ideas? I know Ruby 1.9 replaced Test::Unit with MiniTest which has caused some issues, but after a few hours Googling I haven't found an explanation for this output.

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE (etc.)
Loaded suite /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
.
Finished in 0.030670 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Test run options: --seed 14141
Loaded suite /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails/bin/rake
Started

Finished in 0.003156 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Test run options: --seed 56342
```

Comment: Digging deeper into the source code, each of 'test:units,' 'test:functionals,' and 'test:integration' generates its own section/runs its own suite. So it appears this is intentional behavior?

Comment: If you want to run unit tests only you can use the `test:units` task, for functional tests run `test:functionals` and for integration tests use `test:integration`. The single `test` task run all of them at ones.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it's intentional then. I like RSpec's compact output better.

Comment: Update: Thanks to a bmizerany post on Twitter, I found a formatter for Test::Unit output: https://github.com/TwP/turn (it's available on rubygems.org, just install "turn").